# Fading between shadertoy shaders in p5.js?

Tags: javascript, java, shader, p5.js, fade

I am trying to fade between several different types of shaders from shadertoy by importing them to p5.js and am trying to figure out the best way to do that? I am trying to figure out if I can somehow just use the `tint()` function to adjust the opacity of the shader after I load them in and loop through them, but don't exactly know if that's possible. Here's what I have so far, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the full link to my project at https://glitch.com/~outgoing-island-enthusiasm

```js
    let theShader;
    let oldTime;
    let shaderNdx = 0;

    const shaders = [];

    function preload(){
      // load the shaders
      shaders.push(loadShader('shader1.vert', 'shader1.frag'));
      shaders.push(loadShader('shader2.vert', 'shader2.frag'));
      shaders.push(loadShader('shader3.vert', 'shader3.frag'));
      theShader = shaders[0];  // start with the first shader
    }

    function setup() {
      //creates canvas
      createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight, WEBGL);
      noStroke();
    }

    function draw() {  
      // switch shaders every second
      let time = performance.now() / 1000 | 0;  // convert to seconds
      if (oldTime !== time) {
        oldTime = time;
        // increment shader index to the next shader but wrap around 
        // back to 0 at then of the array of shaders
        shaderNdx = (shaderNdx + 2) % shaders.length;
        theShader = shaders[shaderNdx]
      
      }

      //sets the active shader
      shader(theShader);

      theShader.setUniform("iResolution", [width, height]);
      theShader.setUniform("iFrame", frameCount);
      theShader.setUniform("iMouse", [mouseX, map(mouseY, 0, height, height, 0)]);
      theShader.setUniform("iTime", millis() / 1000.0);
      theShader.setUniform("u_resolution", [width, height]);
      theShader.setUniform("u_time", millis() / 1000.0);
      theShader.setUniform("u_mouse", [mouseX, map(mouseY, 0, height, height, 0)]);

      // rect gives us some geometry on the screen
      rect(0,0,width, height);
    }

    function windowResized(){
      resizeCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
    }
```

Comment: it would be helpful if you could include the shader files in your example, for instance, on glitch.com

Comment: Yep, I just added it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:**
The glitch.com sketch linked below now smoothly transitions between three shaders. There are always 2 active shaders (called `foregroundShader` and `backgroundShader`). Every `changeEvery` frames, the current `foregroundShader` becomes the new `backgroundShader` and a new shader is chosen for the `foregroundShader`. The `backgroundShader` always has alpha of `1.0` (not transparent), whereas the alpha value of the foreground shader linearly increases from `0.0` to `1.0` during the course of one "episode", using the p5.js `map()` function as follows:

```
foregroundShader.setUniform(
    "backgroundAlpha",
    map(frameCount % changeEvery, 0, changeEvery-1, 0.0, 1.0)
);
```

**Original answer:**
A possible solution for smooth transitions between two sketches (I used shaders 1 and 2 from your example in the glitch sketch [here](https://glitch.com/~ordinary-zany-wound)):

Render both shaders on top of each other and give the one on the top a variable alpha (transparency) value, e.g.,

```c
uniform float backgroundAlpha;

...

void main() {
    // Calculate r g b values of your colors somehow
    vec3 color = ...

    // Concatenate the alpha (transparency value)
    gl_FragColor = vec4(color.rgb, backgroundAlpha);
}
```

You can then set the value of backgroundAlpha from your `sketch.js` to some `VALUE`  using `theShader.setUniform('backgroundAlpha', VALUE)`, where `VALUE` could be the output of any function (should be between `0` and `1`).

The same principle should work for three shaders as well.

Note that this first did not work using your glitch sketch because you used an old version of p5.js, that still had a [transparency bug](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/pull/2610/files). It worked, however, using `1.0.0` (see changes in the `index.html` file).

Comment: Ok yeah, that's helpful and makes sense. If I do have a list of say like 5 shaders though and I want to actually change which two shaders are on the top and which is on the bottom, could I do a loop similar to what I had before of switching between different shaders and do a similar thing like what you did with changing the transparency with the background alpha  value?

Comment: @Spencer See the edit in my answer; I changed the sketch accordingly.

Comment: Thank you so much!